# Bash - secure scripts

Tags: apache, bash

I have some questions about security in bash scripts.

I have a script named `test.sh`, which look like

```
#!/bin/bash
cat "$1"
```

Yeah, pretty awesome and innocent script... But when user (like a web user using this cgi-script) give me an argument like
`" ; rm -rf /*"` or use command-substitution `"``rm -rf /*`` `" `` its not a good situation to be in.

So, here is a little test:

```
touch test; ./test.sh " ; `rm test`" &>/dev/null; [[ -f "test" ]] && echo ":)" || echo ":("
```

This will print the sad face.

I know the execution of scripts should run as some predefined user (like apache) with restricted rights. Even accessing the webspace files or resources through this option is a security risk.

This could be easily solved in every script by some regex, etc... But, is this something that really should be solved in script? Or in apache and linux?

Comment: Can you actually produce such a problem with your script as written?  sh doesn't re-evaluate arguments unless you ask it to, so it should be safe as written.  (to the extent that reading any file is considered safe)

Comment: The "little test" doesn't test what you want it to -- the backquoted command (`rm test`) will be executed by the calling shell before test.sh even starts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a bug in your script. Your invocation is equivalent to

```
rm test
./test.sh " ; "
```

There is nothing you can pass in as `$1` that will cause `test.sh` to execute arbitrary commands.

Apart from the ability to read any file, including infinite ones like `/dev/zero` and potentially blocking ones like `/dev/stdin`, the only potential issue is that you can pass in option instead, like `-v`.

This is avoided with

```
cat -- "$1"
```

Bash scripts are generally data safe in themselves, but like SQL injection and system() calls, injection attacks can occur when e.g. `sed`, `awk`, `tar` and tons of other commands are not used correctly, and quoting errors can trigger logic bugs.

These things are rarely related to shell syntax like `` `..` `` or `$(..)` and more related to seemingly innocent strings like "w foo", so they can be hard to filter on a higher level.

Comment: +1. Can you elaborate a bit on `w foo`? Which command does that correspond to?

Comment: `w foo` is sed for writing the pattern space to a file called `foo`. Realistically, you'll need some slashes, commas or other separators and a newline to actually inject it in a setting like `s,something,$var,g`, but that's still pretty benign looking.

Comment: Thanks, that is really something I want to know.